# what does "nuance on tv” mean?

Tags: meaning

> “Doing **nuance on tv** is hard but that’s my job”

That was said by Adam from the tv show “Adam ruins everything” where he debunks myths.

But what does he mean by “nuance on tv”?

Answer (score 2):

"Doing *something* on TV" means providing the specified type or style of entertainment as a television programme. For example, "Doing comedy on TV" means doing some kind of comedy act on a television show. This phrase is often used when somebody wants to describe an aspect of this kind of work, for example:

> Doing mime on radio is pointless

a [nuance](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nuance) is a subtle difference, so

> Doing nuance on TV is hard....

probably means that it is difficult to convey subtle differences through the medium of television.